# ls fails to order files in desired way

Tags: sorting, ls

I have a script that creates files with output_#.root where # is a number. When I do ls in the directory, it chooses to order the files in a weird way:

```
output_1.root
output_10.root
output_100.root
output_11.root
output_2.root
```

etc.

How do I make it order the files in the logical order 1, 2, 3, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files are sorted by alphabetical order. It's normal behavior. If you want to sort them by numerical order, you can try this:

```
ls *.root | sort -k2 -t_ -n
```

This will split your result using `_` as a separator, and order by numerical order `-n` based on the second field `-k2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ls from GNU coreutils you can use the version-sort switch:

```
ls -v
```

Create example files:

```
touch output_1.root output_10.root output_100.root output_11.root output_2.root
```

List them:

```
ls -1v
```

Output:

```
output_1.root
output_2.root
output_10.root
output_11.root
output_100.root
```